# Conditional preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have data in format:
   Randomtext1 (random2,random4)   Randomtext2 (ran dom)   Randomtext3    Randomtext4 (random5,random7,random8)

So I would like to recognize the both the Randomtext-part and the text with in brackets, if it is there with preg_match_all, but im not sure how to get it done. The stuff in the brackets goes together with the Randomtext-part and some of the Randomtext-parts have it and some of them dont.

This is what I have so far, and it works in most cases, but if the text doesnt have any brackets, then it matches the whole thing to one.

`preg_match_all("/([a-zA-Z]+)\s+(?([a-zA-Z, ]*))?/",$text,$matches);`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all("/\b\w+\b(?:\s*\(.*?\)|)/", $text, $matches);
```

Comment: Thank you! With tiny changes I got the pattern changed to get just the information that I needed!

Comment: @Kemu79 - what is the change you have needed to do?

Comment: I changed the pattern to /\b(\w+)\b(?:\s*\((.*?)\)|)/ to save the texts as I needed.